# In an action can I select a partial view to include in my view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action that receives the result of a radio button selection. From that I want to select which partial view to render in the resulting view.

i.e.

```
if radiobutton  =1 
render view with partial1
else if radiobutton =2
render myview with partial2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe just pass the radio button value with ViewBag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just dump the value (or a boolean or whatever else you want to make it more readable) into the ViewBag or ViewData or ViewModel, then read from it on your view:

```
@if (Model.RadioButtonValue == 1) {
    @Html.Partial("Part1")
} else {
    @Html.Partial("Part2")
}

or

<% if ((string)ViewData["radiobutton"] == "1") { %>
   <%= Html.Partial("Part1") %>
<% } else { %>
   <%= Html.Partial("Part2") %>
<% } %>
```

You could also put the name of the partial itself in the ViewBag/ViewData/ViewModel, rather than having the conditional in the view:

```
@Html.Partial(Model.ThePartialName)
```

Comment: I was too focused on doing it in the controller and I missed the obvious... Thanks